# How to show only the matching portions (mimicing the "-o, --only-matching" grep option) in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex, grep

Unix **grep** has a simple `-o, --only-matching` option to show only the part of a matching line that matches PATTERN.

What is the simplest way to mimic that behaviour in Ruby, either using the grep method or any other standard method (without exec or gems)?

Example given:

```
File.open('test.css','r') do |file|
  file.each_line do |line|
    match=/p[A-Z]+/.match(line)
    puts match.to_s unless match.nil?
  end
end
```

would mimic `grep -oE "p[A-Z]+" test.css`.
I suppose there are better (cleaner and more concise) ways.

Comment: use `str.scan`.., `str.scan(/p[A-Z]+/)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking advantage of @avinash-raj, I ended up with this:

```
puts File.open('test.css','r'){|f| f.read.scan(/p[A-Z]+/)}
```

It seems a good deal for file that doesn't take up too much memory space.

Still open to other solutions.

Comment: So, "scan()" is the equivalent of "grep -Eo" ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`String#scan`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-scan) to get an array of all matches:

```
File.foreach('test.css') do |line|
  line.scan(/p[A-Z]+/).each do |match|
    puts match
  end
end
```